# Using a rails instance variable for javascript conditional

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my application_controller.

```
def ensure_service_agreement
  if current_user.agrees_to_service == true
    @tos = true
  else
    @tos = false
  end
end
```

I have the following code in my application.js file.

```
var tos = "<%= @tos %>";
if(tos == false){
  $(".new-session-home").on('click', function (){
      $('.booking.modal')
      .modal('show');
    })
}else{
  $(".new-session-home").on('click', function (){
      $('.tos.modal')
      .modal('show');
    })
}
```

The javascript doesn't seem to register the var tos.  When I set the first if statement to either true or false, I get the second modal (the tos modal)

If I set tos = 4 and then check for that number, it works as it should so I know the problem is with the rails instance variable.

How can I get the JS to understand my instance variable?

Comment: it js file, it can't read erb syntax..

Comment: That's my problem, I need coffeescript then?

Comment: noeps, you need controller_action_name.js.erb

Answer (score 1):

I used the gon gem.

Steps:

gemfile.rb

```
gem 'gon'
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= include_gon %>
```

back to my application_controller.rb

```
def ensure_service_agreement
 if current_user.agrees_to_service == true
  @tos = true
  gon.tos = true
 else
  @tos = false
  gon.tos = false
 end
end
```

and finally my js

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    if(gon.tos == true) {
              $('.booking.modal').modal('show');
              console.log(date)
    } else {
              $('.tos.modal').modal('show');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to manipulate rails code in js file. But you will not get any erb syntax there.

There are multiple solution to solve this kind of request. If you are submitting form or redirecting to some url, Then you can use ujs to do this (Using `:remote => true`).

UJS respond in `.js.erb` file there you can access both js and erb syntax.

If you are not submitting or there is no url change then you can easily do this with jquery only. like

```
<a href='#' onclick="somefunction(true/false)">booking/tos</a>
```

As your code structure you should go for UJS.

Comment: I need to manipulate a callback based on a rails boolean.  It's loading different modals, no URI changes.

Comment: You can use UJS for this. You must be on some controller which is associated to this callback. `someaction.js.erb`

Comment: You can follow this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3--net-15243

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, this is an ideal solution.

You have set the value in `ensure_service_agreement` method.

Use renderer file like `ensure_service_agreement.js.erb` or `ensure_service_agreement.html.erb`

and keep the value in input tag.

```
<input name='' id='tos' value = '<%= @tos %>'> use type hidden or style with display:none
```

and access in Js file like

```
var tos = $('#tos').val();
```

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate a callback from a jquery library based on my boolean, I'm not submitting a form. There is no input tag.